# What is the term for when a person lies in front of the group during a picture?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the term for when someone is lying down in front of the group during a picture?

For example:

During the group photo, Ben decided to (lie in front).

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used. Are you looking for a term to describe just the person or the whole group?

Comment: Done. I have added an edit.

Comment: Do you mean _photobombing_?

Comment: If you mean a group photo with one row standing, one row sitting and one or two people lying down, I've never heard a special word for it.

Comment: Do you mean as in this photo? https://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/clintonherald.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/b/35/b35b9e06-5d71-11ea-8bba-37247b5d59b9/5e5e91571713a.image.jpg?resize=1200%2C865

Comment: There are different ways of lying, is it: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-woman-774427.jpg  OR https://previews.123rf.com/images/paulphoto/paulphoto1712/paulphoto171200031/92403776-portrait-of-six-children-having-good-time-in-the-park-asian-children-lying-down-together-on-green-gr.jpg ?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for the sample sentence. It still needs a little clarifying, though: A number of folks are assuming you're talking about the social behavior of putting yourself in the picture, or choosing the front, but it might also be that you're just asking about the bodily position (in which case a word like "reclining" might be on the right track). Can you edit to narrow it down?